# Pull Up Print Dialog In Notepad

Tags: c#

What I'm trying to do is create a Windows Journal (.jrn) file from a .txt. This conversion can be done by printing to a virtual "Journal Note Writer" printer. I've been struggling with a few different methods of getting this to work for a while now, so I've decided to try to simplify things (I hope).

**What I Currently Have**

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = fileToOpen, // My .txt file I'd like to convert to a .jrn
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    Arguments = "-print-dialog -exit-on-print"
};
p.Start();
```

This opens the file in Notepad, but does not open the print dialog. I'd like for the print dialog to open and ideally to be able to specify some default options in the print dialog.

Another thing I've tried is this (found in another SO question):

```
Process p = new Process( );
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo( )
{
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    Verb = "print",
    FileName = fileToOpen
};
p.Start( );
```

The problem with this is that it just automatically prints the file to the default printer (a physical one) without giving me the option to change it.

**What I'm Looking For**

At this point I'm just looking for any way to print a .txt to "Windows Note Writer." I've tried doing the printing without going through an external application, and had some trouble with that as well. I haven't been able to find any other references to converting to a .jrn file, so I'm open to ANY ideas.

Comment: Maybe this article is helpful? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091 Sorry I haven't tried it myself, but I'm at work...

Comment: @Picacodigos - Thank you for the link. It looks like it may be worth a shot if I'm unable to get printing through Notepad working. I've tried approaches somewhat similar to this, but I was hoping to get away from having to use a printer helper class.

Comment: Just another idea. Have you tried ShellExecute(ing) the DOS command "TYPE <filename> > LPT1" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1472153/18192 suggests this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwbe712d.aspx .  It's a bit simpler than Picacodigos' suggestion, as it instructs specifically how to print a text file rather than printing data in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with this issue for a while, I decided to go back to trying the handle the printing directly through the application without going through Notepad. The issue I was having before when I tried this was that changing the paper size would break the resulting .jrn file (the printout would be blank). It turns out that changing some paper size settings was necessary to print on a non-native paper size.

Below is the final code in case anybody else struggles with this issue. Thanks for everybody's help.

```
private void btnOpenAsJRN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string fileToOpen = this.localDownloadPath + "\\" + this.filenameToDownload;
    //Create a StreamReader object
    reader = new StreamReader(fileToOpen);
    //Create a Verdana font with size 10
    lucida10Font = new Font("Lucida Console", 10);
    //Create a PrintDocument object
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();

    PaperSize paperSize = new PaperSize("Custom", 400, 1097);
    paperSize.RawKind = (int)PaperKind.Custom;
    pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize;
    pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(20, 20, 30, 30);

    pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["journalNotePrinter"];
    pd.DocumentName = this.filenameToDownload;
    //Add PrintPage event handler
    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.PrintTextFileHandler);

    //Call Print Method
    try {
        pd.Print();
    }
    finally {
        //Close the reader
        if (reader != null) {
            reader.Close();
        }
        this.savedJnt = fileToOpen.Replace("txt", "jnt");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        if (File.Exists(this.savedJnt)) {
            lblJntSaved.Visible = true;
            lblJntSaved.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            lblJntSaved.Text = "File successfully located.";
            // If the file can be found, show all of the buttons for completing 
            // the final steps.
            lblFinalStep.Visible = true;
            btnMoveToSmoketown.Visible = true;
            btnEmail.Visible = true;
            txbEmailAddress.Visible = true;
        }
        else {
            lblJntSaved.Visible = true;
            lblJntSaved.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblJntSaved.Text = "File could not be located. Please check your .jnt location.";
        }
    }
}

private void PrintTextFileHandler(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ppeArgs) {
    //Get the Graphics object
    Graphics g = ppeArgs.Graphics;
    float linesPerPage = 0;
    float yPos = 0;
    int count = 0;
    //Read margins from PrintPageEventArgs
    float leftMargin = ppeArgs.MarginBounds.Left;
    float topMargin = ppeArgs.MarginBounds.Top;
    string line = null;
    //Calculate the lines per page on the basis of the height of the page and the height of the font
    linesPerPage = ppeArgs.MarginBounds.Height /
    lucida10Font.GetHeight(g);
    //Now read lines one by one, using StreamReader
    while (count < linesPerPage &&
    ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)) {
        //Calculate the starting position
        yPos = topMargin + (count *
        lucida10Font.GetHeight(g));
        //Draw text
        g.DrawString(line, lucida10Font, Brushes.Black,
        leftMargin, yPos, new StringFormat());
        //Move to next line
        count++;
    }
    //If PrintPageEventArgs has more pages to print
    if (line != null) {
        ppeArgs.HasMorePages = true;
    }
    else {
        ppeArgs.HasMorePages = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get `Journal Note Writer` as printer you would have to add it into the printer preferences -> Add Printer (I wonder whether it could be done programmatically).

Anyways you can always get a print of a plain .txt file as described here at [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287530(v=vs.71).aspx).