# How to print a text file using C#

Tags: c#, printing, console

How can I print a text file in C#? In a console application.

This is what I've found: [msdn sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287530%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and this [stackoverflow:answer is the msdn sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472153/print-a-txt-to-the-default-printer-with-c-sharp)

The code from the links are for windows forms applications, and does'nt work in an console appliction.

Here is what I've found:

```
    string fileName = @"C:\data\stuff.txt";
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo;
        startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName);

        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (String verb in startInfo.Verbs)
            {
                // Display the possible verbs.
                Console.WriteLine("  {0}. {1}", i.ToString(), verb);
                i++;
            }
        }

        startInfo.Verb = "print";
        Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Since you say this question is off topic and not relevant here is a link to what I'm trying to learn: [This is documentation of the .Net framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/hh156542) and this is why I'm asking the question, I'm trying to learn about the various uses of .Net classes.

Comment: Have you written any code? What have you tried? Any errors?

Comment: Have you done a google search ?

Comment: You'll have to explain why those links didn't work for you. If you don't your question might get closed as a dupe

Comment: The link is for winform not a console app

Comment: You can use `System.Windows.WinForms` in a console app...

Comment: I don't know anything about the code, I'm learning C# and was looking for code to try to understand and work with, I have alot of books on C# but wanted to practice on something else, as I was a little bored with reading, and punching code. Just want some fresh samples to look at and understand, to do some specific tasks, like printing an document from my program.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the PRINT verb to print a file to the default printer using the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) and [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) classes:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\temp\output.txt");
psi.Verb = "PRINT";

Process.Start(psi);
```

If you want to make sure the file has been sent to printer before continuing, use `Process.WaitForExit()`. It may be required, for example, to prevent deletion of that file before it has been printed:

```
static void PrintText( string text )
{   string           filegen, filetxt;
    ProcessStartInfo psi;
    Process          proc;

    filegen = Path.GetTempFileName();
    filetxt = filegen + ".txt";
    File.Move( filegen, filetxt );
    File.AppendAllText( filetxt, text  );

    psi = new ProcessStartInfo( filetxt );
    psi.Verb = "PRINT";
    proc = Process.Start( psi );
    proc.WaitForExit();
    File.Delete( filetxt );
}
```