# Printing a Text file programmatically

Tags: c#, printing, process, diagnostics

I'm tring to make a program that saves a textbox text to a text file and prints the text file.

I found this code:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"TempDocument.txt");
psi.Verb = "PRINT";
Process.Start(psi);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839800/how-to-print-a-text-file-using-c-sharp)

But it doesn't open a dialog it's just printing.

I want to have a dialog in order to choose another printer or open in OneNote.

Comment: Have you tried  google? the search for `c# open printdialog` returns 75 000 results. like this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/289705/how-to-open-print-dialog-box-in-my-csharp-applicat

Answer (score 1):

To show a printDialog, you can try : 
However, I don't know which kind of project your talking about, so maybe this will not fit.

```
printDialog = new PrintDialog();
            //when you click on OK
            if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
            //path is your documents to print location 
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
            info.Arguments = "\"" + printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName + "\"";
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            info.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            info.UseShellExecute = true;
            info.Verb = "PrintTo";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info);
            }
```