# c# Print string *directly* to printer

Tags: c#, printing

I need to print a string exactly as it is without drawing a picture before printing.
`Graphic.DrawString` Draws the specified text string, so I DO NOT want to use that - It draws a picture of the string. What I need is the exact string.

The only solution I found is to send a file to the printer - but I don't like that solution..

Comment: you mean printing in plain text mode? which OS/driver stack/printer model? sending a file to the printer is a robust solution. it wraps the complexity of communicating with a printer port for you. if you don't want that, you'll have to deal with the spooler subsystem yourself, or write to the hardware port.

Comment: My problem is that I am trying to print to a card printer, and usually it checks what text it is printing, and if it hits a '~' it then encodes the magnetic stripe.
When i print from Microsoft word, or Access, it works fine because text is sent to the printer.
But using "PrintDocument" object and drawing to a bitmap, it is unable to parse the text.

Comment: `but I don't like that solution..` Please make clear **in your question** why you don't like it.

Comment: _from Microsoft word, or Access, it works fine because text is sent to the printer._ How do you know that? Can you observe the data stream? Do you have access to the printer's documentation? Even in the old days you needed to know how to tell the printer that you would start sending text. So without the proper control codes you couldn't & can't simply dump text. Sending a file probbly will trigger those control codes..

Comment: Thank you.  mjwills - I don't like it because I need to send a raw string (not a drawing string) to the printer and on the same printing, I do need to send a drawing string.  I will try to clearly with an example:  - I need to send "~1;125?" Exactly like that (the printer driver knows to identify that string that it should be encoded the magnet stripe. and then. I need to send something like:  pageEventArgs.Graphics.DrawString(Arguments.PassengerLastName, bold, brush, 220, 145);

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44806393/159275

Answer (score 1):

Nowdays printers is not writing machines.
In order to print anything, you got to draw a picture of it first. Keep in mind that not all pictures are jpg files.
One solution is stream your output to txt file and prompt printDialog